# SoftReferences vs Weakreferences / OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, reference, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, weak

I got a problem dealing with soft and weak references. Code has a flag that switches
all logic between soft and weak references. And while with weak references all seems
to be working ok, with soft references I am consistently getting OutOfMemoryError.
That happens with JDK7 and JDK6 on MacOSX as well as with IcedTea6 on Debian.
However, JDK7 with G1 collector is a setup I found working with soft references,
everything else I tried (serial/parallel GC, -client/-server, etc) failed throwing
the exception.

Code is a bit big but I have tried to narrow it down as much as possible while preserving the issue.
I left a massive comment on top of it describing in a greater detail how to reproduce
the issue.

```
/*
 *
 * Leakling.java
 *
 *
 * Issue:
 *
 *
 *   This code throws OutOfMemoryError when using soft references, whereas weak references
 *   work ok. Moreover, with JDK7 G1 garbage collector soft references work as well. Other
 *   collectors seem to fail. Code was tested with MacOSX 10.8.2 JDKs 1.7.0_10-b18 and
 *   1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909, with Debian 6.0 IcedTea6 1.8.13.
 *   Various command line options including -Xmx, -client/-server, -XX:+UseParallelOldGC,
 *   -XX:+UseSerialGC were tested.
 *
 *
 * Examples:
 *
 *
 * 1. Default options, weak references, this works, counters go up and down,
 *    but everything keeps going just as expected:
 *
 *   java -Xmx50m Leakling \
 *       --loop-delay=10 --min-chunk-size=1000 --max-chunk-size=100000 --use-soft-references=false
 *
 *
 * 2. Default options, soft references, this eventually throws the exception:
 *
 *   java -Xmx50m Leakling \
 *       --loop-delay=10 --min-chunk-size=1000 --max-chunk-size=100000 --use-soft-references=true
 *
 *
 * 3. G1 collector (IcedTea6 doesn't support it), weak references, this works, but it did anyway:
 *
 *   java -XX:+UseG1GC -Xmx50m Leakling \
 *       --loop-delay=10 --min-chunk-size=1000 --max-chunk-size=100000 --use-soft-references=false
 *
 *
 * 4. G1 collector, soft references, this works with JDK7.
 *    JDK6 seems to just stop after having hit memory limit (with no message whatsoever).
 *
 *   java -XX:+UseG1GC -Xmx50m Leakling \
 *       --loop-delay=10 --min-chunk-size=1000 --max-chunk-size=100000 --use-soft-references=true
 *
 *
 * jarek, 02.01.2013
 *
 *
 */

import java.lang.ref.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Leakling {
  private static final String TAG = "memory-chunk-";


  class Chunk {
    final String name;
    final int size;
    final private byte[] mem;

    Chunk(String name, int minSize, int maxSize, Random randomizer) {
      int currSize = minSize;
      if (maxSize > minSize) {
        currSize += randomizer.nextInt(maxSize - minSize + 1);
      }
      this.size = currSize;
      this.mem = new byte[currSize];
      this.name = name;
      log(this + " has been created (" + currSize + " bytes)");
    }

    @Override
    public void finalize() throws Throwable {
      log(this + " is finalizing");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return name + " of " + getReadableMemorySize(size);
    }
  }


  class WeakChunk extends WeakReference<Chunk> {
    final String name;

    public WeakChunk(Chunk chunk, ReferenceQueue<Chunk> queue) {
      super(chunk, queue);
      this.name = chunk.name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "weak reference of " + name + " is " + ((get() == null) ? "null" : "alive");
    }
  }


  class SoftChunk extends SoftReference<Chunk> {
    final String name;

    public SoftChunk(Chunk chunk, ReferenceQueue<Chunk> queue) {
      super(chunk, queue);
      this.name = chunk.name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "soft reference of " + name + " is " + ((get() == null) ? "null" : "alive");
    }
  }

  // Logging as implemented here gives extra timing info (secs.milis starting from the initialization).
  private final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
  private final Formatter formatter = new Formatter(System.err);
  private final String formatString = "%1$d.%2$03d %3$s\n";

  // I found this be better synchronized...
  synchronized void log(Object o) {
    long curr = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long diff = curr - start;
    formatter.format(formatString, (int) (diff / 1000), (int) (diff % 1000), o.toString());
  }

  private final ArrayList<Chunk> allChunks = new ArrayList<Chunk>();
  private final ReferenceQueue<Chunk> softReferences = new ReferenceQueue<Chunk>();
  private final ReferenceQueue<Chunk> weakReferences = new ReferenceQueue<Chunk>();
  private final HashSet<Reference<Chunk>> allReferences = new HashSet<Reference<Chunk>>();
  private final Random randomizer = new Random();

  private int loopDelay = 200;
  private int minChunkSize = 100;
  private int maxChunkSize = 1000;
  private int chunkCounter = 0;
  private boolean useSoftReferences = false;
  private long minMemory = 10 * 1024 * 1024;  // Default range is 10-30MB
  private long maxMemory = 3 * minMemory;
  private long usedMemory = 0;

  private String getReadableMemorySize(long size) {
    if (size >= 1024 * 1024) {
      return (float) (Math.round((((float) size) / 1024f / 1024f) * 10f)) / 10f + "MB";
    }
    if (size >= 1024) {
      return (float) (Math.round((((float) size) / 1024f) * 10f)) / 10f + "kB";
    } else if (size > 0) {
      return size + "B";
    } else {
      return "0";
    }
  }

  private void allocMem() {
    Chunk chunk = new Chunk(TAG + chunkCounter++, minChunkSize, maxChunkSize, randomizer);
    allChunks.add(chunk);
    Reference ref = useSoftReferences
            ? (new SoftChunk(chunk, softReferences)) : (new WeakChunk(chunk, weakReferences));
    allReferences.add(ref);
    log(ref);
    usedMemory += chunk.size;
  }

  private void freeMem() {
    if (allChunks.size() < 1) {
      return;
    }
    int i = randomizer.nextInt(allChunks.size());
    Chunk chunk = allChunks.get(i);
    log("freeing " + chunk);
    usedMemory -= chunk.size;
    allChunks.remove(i);
  }

  private int statMem() throws Exception {
    for (Reference ref; (ref = softReferences.poll()) != null;) {
      log(ref);
      allReferences.remove(ref);
    }
    for (Reference ref; (ref = weakReferences.poll()) != null;) {
      log(ref);
      allReferences.remove(ref);
    }
    int weakRefs = 0;
    int softRefs = 0;
    for (Iterator<Reference<Chunk>> i = allReferences.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
      Reference<Chunk> ref = i.next();
      if (ref.get() == null) {
        continue;
      }
      if (ref instanceof WeakChunk) {
        weakRefs++;
      }
      if (ref instanceof SoftChunk) {
        softRefs++;
      }
    }
    log(allChunks.size() + " chunks, "
            + softRefs + " soft refs, "
            + weakRefs + " weak refs, "
            + getReadableMemorySize(usedMemory) + " used, "
            + getReadableMemorySize(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()) + " free, "
            + getReadableMemorySize(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()) + " total, "
            + getReadableMemorySize(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()) + " max");
    if (loopDelay > 1) {
      Thread.sleep(loopDelay);
    }
    return (int)((100 * usedMemory) / maxMemory); // Return % of maxMemory being used.
  }

  public Leakling(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for (String arg : args) {
      if (arg.startsWith("--min-memory=")) {
        minMemory = Long.parseLong(arg.substring("--min-memory=".length()));
      } else if (arg.startsWith("--max-memory=")) {
        maxMemory = Long.parseLong(arg.substring("--max-memory=".length()));
      } else if (arg.startsWith("--min-chunk-size=")) {
        minChunkSize = Integer.parseInt(arg.substring("--min-chunk-size=".length()));
      } else if (arg.startsWith("--max-chunk-size=")) {
        maxChunkSize = Integer.parseInt(arg.substring("--max-chunk-size=".length()));
      } else if (arg.startsWith("--loop-delay=")) {
        loopDelay = Integer.parseInt(arg.substring("--loop-delay=".length()));
      } else if (arg.startsWith("--use-soft-references=")) {
        useSoftReferences = Boolean.parseBoolean(arg.substring("--use-soft-references=".length()));
      } else {
        throw new Exception("Unknown command line option...");
      }
    }
  }

  public void run() throws Exception {
    log("Mem test started...");

    while(true) {
      log("going up...");
      do {// First loop allocates memory up to the given limit in a pseudo-random fashion.
          // Randomized rate of allocations/frees is about 4:1 as per the 10>=8 condition.
        if (randomizer.nextInt(10) >= 8) {
          freeMem();
        } else {
          allocMem();
        }
      } while (statMem() < 90); // Repeat until 90% of the given mem limit is hit...

      log("going down...");
      do {// Now do the reverse. Frees are four times more likely than allocations are.
        if (randomizer.nextInt(10) < 8) {
          freeMem();
        } else {
          allocMem();
        }
      } while (usedMemory > minMemory);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    (new Leakling(args)).run();
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) What's the accompanying message that comes with OOME? 2) You can't expect people to look at the whole code. You should edit it down to its essence and post it here as opposed to use pastebin.

Comment: how fast do you approach OOME?

Comment: I did narrow down the code, it is still big though. Exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at Leakling$Chunk.<init>(Leakling.java:68)
 at Leakling.allocMem(Leakling.java:156)
 at Leakling.run(Leakling.java:242)
 at Leakling.main(Leakling.java:258)
And repro is simple, compile, copy & paste command from comment in code. No analysis needed for this.

Comment: Isn't the whole `// Now do the reverse. Frees are four times more likely than allocations are.` loop problematic? If you keep getting 8, 9, 10 it will just keep allocating memory, won't it?

Comment: In the examples I set -Xmx50m and code has internal limit set at 30MB, last line of out looks more or less like "12.384 281 chunks, 953 soft refs, 0 weak refs, 12.4MB used, 2.1MB free, 47.9MB total, 47.9MB max" - soft references don't seem to be released. Besides, I never have issue with exactly the same conditions using weak refs.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, don't mix finalizers w/ References.  both have an impact on how quickly an object can be removed from memory, and everything you can do with a finalizer can be done better with the appropriate Reference type.

Second, as i mentioned, there may be a gc delay associated with using references.  At least for the "common" gc algorithms, weakly/softly referenced objects may take an extra gc run before they are fully reclaimed.  The essential different between weak and soft references are that weak references are aggressively gc'ed and soft references are generally held "as long as possible".  this is most likely what is getting you.

when you run with weakly referenced objects, stuff gets cleaned up as you go, allowing you to avoid OOME.

when you run with softly referenced objects, all the softly referenced objects are *held until you get close to the limit*.  then, when memory gets tight, the gc tries to start releasing softly referenced objects, but it takes too long (since it may require multiple gc passes to completely reclaim the memory) and you end up getting an OOME.

i only have superficial knowledge of the G1 gc, so i don't know why it "works" in that scenaior.

in summary, soft references are kind of nice, but they don't always work out as well as you would like due to the reclamation delay.  also, this is a [great article](http://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=java.refobj) with some additional useful details.

Comment: G1 happens to work only with JDK7 (maybe it triggers expunging the soft refs early enough to avoid the issue). JDK6 doesn't even show any message at all with G1 turned on, just quits with exit code == 1.

Answer (score 5):

Get rid of the finalizer.

Object finalization happens in a separate thread, and the memory cannot be truly reclaimed until after finalization completes. In your finalizer you're making a system call (the output), which will introduce a wait into that thread. It's very easy, when you're at the limits of memory, for any finalizer wait to cause an OOM.

As for the soft versus weak difference: we references will be reclaimed during minor collections, while soft references will not be (I haven't checked that; it may be that the flag that controls lifetime of a soft reference will simply allow it to live over multiple minor collections). It's very likely that your finalizer thread can keep up with the discarded weakly-referenced objects.

Comment: Removing the finalizer worked. Empty finalizer works too, so it seems to ne the I/O timing really. I will reconsider logic to keep the logging for now. Thanks.

Comment: If you look at the article that @jtahlborn linked, you'll find a program that runs out of memory when there are no program-level references of any kind. All because of a slow finalizer.